# AWS SDK for .NET - IAmazonS3 does not contain definition for 'PutObject'

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am trying to create a Lambda function that will allow a user to upload a document to S3. To do this I am following the documentation for the SDK that says that there is a method "PutObject" to allow me to put an object into a bucket. When I code this I get the following compile error:

> IAmazonS3 does not contain definition for 'PutObject' and no extension
>   method 'PutObject' accepting first argument of type 'IAmazonS3' could
>   be found.

Here is the code that I am working with currently:

```
S3Client = new AmazonS3Client("*********", "**********************", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest();
putRequest.BucketName = _bucket;
putRequest.ContentType = ContentType;
putRequest.ContentBody = Bytes;
var s3Response = S3Client.PutObject(putRequest);
return s3Response.HttpStatusCode.ToString();
```

I have updated all my NuGet packages and have the AWSSDK.S3 v3.3.5.3 package installed. When I look through the object browser I only see Async methods. There is no listing of the PutObject method that is mentioned in the documentation. Can anyone point me in the right direction of why this is not working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're seeing the **Async** operations only, your project could be either a Portable Class Library or a Unity project since NuGet Package Manager will install the correct assemblies depending on your project type.

> For PCL and Unity this operation is only available in asynchronous
>   form.

See [AmazonS3Client.PutObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/MS3PutObjectPutObjectRequest.html).

**UPDATE**

The same applies if you're using **.NET Core**:

> The AWS SDK for .NET supports applications written for .NET Core. AWS
>   service clients only support asynchronous calling patterns in .NET
>   core. This also affects many of the high level abstractions built on
>   top of service clients like Amazon S3's `TransferUtility` which will
>   only support asynchronous calls in the .NET Core environment. For
>   details, see [Configuring the AWS SDK for .NET with .NET Core](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-netcore.html).

See [Platforms Supported by the AWS SDK for .NET](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-platform-diffs-v3.html).

Comment: I am using the template from the SDK toolkit names "AWS Lambda Project (.NET Core)". Am I mistaken that this does not fall into one of those two categories?

Comment: AWS service clients only support asynchronous calling patterns in .NET core. See my updated answer.

Comment: I was gonna add that. .NET Core does not support the regular S3Client, only the Async ones.

Comment: Your first link seems to be broken now, probably useful: [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpNET.html](Upload an Object Using the AWS SDK for .NET)

Comment: @BenceLászló Thanks for the tip :) I've updated the broken link.